# PHP y HTML:Hoja de estilos no reacciona

Tags: php, html, css

Una disculpa, mi hoja de estilos no esta funcionando para nada. Aun, me manda el estilo muy diferente en un php y en el html. Exactamente con el mismo codigo, misma hoja, pero me lo da diferente. Aqui dejare imagenes para que puedan ver que hace. Esta todo igual, solo cambia la extension. Tambien, modifico algo de la hoja de estilos y esta modificacion no tiene ningun efecto, sobretodo en php.

Aqui esta el .php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el .html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Ambas tienen tienen el mismo codigo

Comment: Tienes el css en un archivo externo? Puedes colocar cómo haces el linkeado?

Comment: Sin el código no puede saberse qué está mal.
Pero por el print de la función php en la pantalla el problema es alguna llave o elemento mal cerrado.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos de nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos de busqueda.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo de resultados.css">

El de esta pagina es el estilo de resultados.css

Answer (score 1):

Opción 1: Cambia el nombre de las archivos .css (eliminando los espacios, puedes colocar un guión bajo en su lugar).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_de_nav.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_de_busqueda.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo_de_resultados.css">
```

---

Opción 2: Que estás haciendo el llamado a los archivos y se encuentra en una ruta diferente. Si tienes los archivos en una carpeta, por ejemplo css debes colocar el nombre de la carpeta, diagonal y el nombre del archivo.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_de_nav.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_de_busqueda.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo_de_resultados.css">
```

---

Opción 3: Haces el llamado desde una subcarpeta donde no se encuentra el archivo, en ese caso debes colocar `../` para indicar que debe ir una carpeta antes y luego, dependiendo si el archivo está en esa carpeta colocar el nombre del archivo o el nombre de la carpeta y luego el nombre del archivo.

```
//En caso de que se encuentre en la carpeta anterior
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos_de_nav.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos_de_busqueda.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilo_de_resultados.css">

//En caso de que se encuentre en una sub-carpeta
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos_de_nav.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos_de_busqueda.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo_de_resultados.css">
```

---

En el `href` debe ir la ruta exacta donde se encuentra el archivo, para saber si estás haciendo bien el linkeado aprieta `ctrl+u` en la página donde tienes el problema, busca el link de cualquier .css y entra, si te sale que no existe es porque el archivo .css no está bien linkeado.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usa click derecho en el navegador.
2. Selecciona `Inspecionar Elemento`.

En esta parte veras cosas como esta:

```
<div id="" select class=" form" control" element (etc...) >elemetos</div>
```

Si lo estas autogenerando el `TEXTO` con `PHP` en caso de que sea, seria mejor que use `\"` o `\'` para delimitar

Tambien agrega parte de código